# ionic 3 native storage read value stored

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3, cordova-nativestorage

**Hello,**

in my code I tried the code written on the page of the Native Storage plugin which is here : [Native Storage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/)

```
    import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) { }

...

this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );

this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

When I launch my android simulator device the console sends me back this :

```
[00:02:01]  console.log: Stored item! 
[00:02:01]  console.log: [object Object]
```

[image: console]

I would like to find a solution to read the stored information. Because I would like to use a value stored in native storage to make a condition on an external page and I can not. Example "If the value stored on native storage of the name Vibrator is == to true then we start this function". I am looking for the method to read the value. Can you help me?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the value, call it like this:

```
console.log(data.property);
console.log(data.anotherProperty);
```

Refer to the plugin github to get a clearer understanding: https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the value like that since it is an `Async` operation.You just tried to `copy/paste` the doc's code. That is not the real use case of usage. It's just an example.

This is the real use case simulation. You store the value as shown below.

*my-first-page.ts*

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

After that on the 2nd page, you can retrieve a value like below.

*my-second-page.ts*

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
   },
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

**Note:** If you need further help please let me know.

Comment: I did exactly as you said but no luck. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you explained, I added property value I wanted "property". I put in ***Home.ts***

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

and in ***parameter.ts*** I put

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data.property),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

When I run the simulator my console tells me when I fall on the pace home.ts

```
[10:30:06]  console.log: Stored item! 
[10:30:06]  console.log: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
[10:30:06]  console.log: Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 4017 m
s
```

and when I click on the page parameter.ts here is the result that I have

```
[10:56:17]  console.log: value 
[10:56:17]  console.error: [object Object]
```

I get well the value of "property" which is equal to "value".

thanks guys